# Error while running U-Net image segmentation

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I am building a U-net for image segmentation, the images are grayscale (x-ray), the masks are binary(black and white). when I run the following code I receive the below error.

```
seed = 42
np.random.seed = seed
IMG_WIDTH = 256 
IMG_HEIGHT = 256
IMG_CHANNELS = 1 

TRAIN_PATH = '/content/stage1_train/stage1_train/'
TEST_PATH = '/content/stage1_test/stage1_test/'

train_ids = next(os.walk(TRAIN_PATH))[1]
test_ids = next(os.walk(TEST_PATH))[1]

X_train =np.zeros((len(train_ids),IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH,IMG_CHANNELS),dtype=np.uint8)
Y_train =np.zeros((len(train_ids),IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH,1),dtype=np.bool) # what to predict 1 is boolean yes or no 

print('resizing training images and masks')
for n, id_ in tqdm(enumerate(train_ids), total=len(train_ids)):
  path = TRAIN_PATH + id_
  img = imread(path + '/images/' + id_+'.png')[:,:,:IMG_CHANNELS]
  img = resize(img, (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH), mode='constant', preserve_range=True)
  X_train[n]=img #fill empty x_train with valus from img
  mask= np.zeros((IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH, 1), dtype=np.bool)
  for mask_file in next(os.walk(path+'/omasks/'))[2]:
    mask_=imread(path +'/masks/'+ mask_file)
    mask_=np.expand_dims(resize(mask_,(IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH),mode= 'constant',preserve_range=True),axis=-1)
    mask =np.maximum(mask,mask_)

    Y_train[n]= mask
```

I am receiving this error on line 29 is there an extra step to be done or should I delete something:

```
resizing training images and masks
  0%|          | 0/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-b6553d1e2c0c> in <module>()
     27 for n, id_ in tqdm(enumerate(train_ids), total=len(train_ids)):
     28   path = TRAIN_PATH + id_
---> 29   img = imread(path + '/images/' + id_+'.png')[:,:,:IMG_CHANNELS]
     30   img = resize(img, (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH), mode='constant', preserve_range=True)
     31   X_train[n]=img #fill empty x_train with valus from img

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 2-dimensional, but 3 were indexed
```

Comment: `array is 2-dimensional` means that the image you are reading only has 2 dimensions and you try to acess three: `[:,:,:IMG_CHANNELS]`.
If you want your image to have one extra channel, you can expand the dimensions via:
`imread(path + '/images/' + id_+'.png')[:,:,np.newaxis]`

Comment: I tried your suggestion it works without showing an error in that part but another error appeared. @Chillston
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

---> 32     mask =np.maximum(mask,mask_)
     33 
     34     Y_train[n]= mask

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (256,256,1) (256,256,4,1)

Comment: You take the maximum of two tensors with different rank, you could shrink `mask_`: `np.maximum(mask, mask_[...,0])`
That way the shapes are
`mask: (256,256,1)`
and
`mask_: (256,256,4)`
this is broadcastable then